# Awesomenauts abilities that do not damage turrets

Tags: awesomenauts

[Coco](http://awesomenauts.wikia.com/wiki/Coco_Nebulon)’s [ball lightning](http://awesomenauts.wikia.com/wiki/Ball_Lightning) and [Ayla](http://awesomenauts.wikia.com/wiki/Ayla)’s [Rage](http://awesomenauts.wikia.com/wiki/Rage) seem to not damage turrets (or the base).

Which other abilities also do not do such damage? Is there such a reference list online of these?

Answer (score 4):

Many abilities do reduced damage against turrets, as for ones that do not do any I think is very limited. This list should make it easier to test or calculate. http://awesomenauts.wikia.com/wiki/Turret :)

Comment: Thank you. I’ve upvoted the answer since it lists reduced damages, but haven’t marked it as accepted since it doesn't list (but references). abilities that do no damage.

Comment: Thanks, and yeah that's fair, I couldn't find a list anywhere, and I figured the best way would be to test it out in practice mode and thought this would eliminate some abilities. :)